# How to loop through this Array and output to html?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

I have a simple array that I'm having the hardest time trying to sort. I'm thinking maybe it's because of the time format, so I'm unsure how to reference it or how I could sort the time, in this array format, so that I can sort it later.

//function created to input values
    function put(key, value, obj) {
        obj[key] = value;
        return obj
    }

```
//loads the document from ajax call
function loadDoc() {
//ajax call
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var data = xhttp.responseText;
//input data from webpage into dom element
    document.getElementById('next').innerHTML = data
    var test = document.getElementsByClassName('gridRow')
//create dict
    var new_dict = {}
    for(a=0;a<test.length;a++){
        if(test[a].children[2].innerText == 'Ready') {
            test[a].style.display = 'none';
            //drops into the dictionary
            put(String(test[a].children[0].innerText).replace(/\n/ig, ''), 
test[a].children[3].innerText, new_dict)
            }
    }
document.getElementById('next').innerHTML = ''  

//looping through the dict
for(var index in new_dict) {
  document.getElementById('next').innerHTML += ("<br>" + index + " : " + 
new_dict[index] + "<br>");
}
```

the output is the same order the names appear.

Comment: "_I'm having the hardest time trying to sort_" Where are you trying to sort?

Comment: Doesn't look like your for loop is completely shown here, also - where is the new_dict array declared?

Comment: please share the code regarding to creating array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the way your array seems to be populated, and going for the simplist solution:  why don't you just normalize the time value such that you have appropriately pre-pended 0s?

" john doe": "00:19:57"
" Guy Faux ": "00:36:40"
" Charles Sheen ": "01:35:37"

Comment: Sounds simple enough, let me try that.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever is creating `new_dict` is creating it incorrectly. It's an array, but the code creating it is using it like a plain object. I'd fix that so that it's, for instance, an array of objects.

But with your current structure:

If you want to loop through its properties in order alphabetically by the property names, you can use `Object.keys` to get the keys and sort it, then loop through the result via `map` creating the output:

```
document.getElementById('next').innerHTML = Object.keys(new_dict)
    .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))     // Sorts lexicographically (loosely, "alphabetically")
    .map(key => escapeHTML(key + ": " + new_dict[key]))
    .join("<br>");                          // Joins them with <br> in-between
}
```

...where `escapeHTML` encodes `&` and `<`, since you're generating HTML. A quick and dirty version (which is good enough for the above) would be something like:

```
// ONLY good enough to handle text that isn't in attributes
function escapeHTML(str) {
    return str.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;");
}
```

Comment: This worked after modifying my Dict to include leading 0's like @user1211530 suggested

Answer (score 1):

This is a dictionary, not an array.  It would be more accurate to refer to the names as "keys" and not "indexes".  In particular, the dictionary you have here maps names onto times.  Anyway, one thing you could do is make a new dictionary that maps the times onto a list of names (as multiple names might have the same time).  Then sort that dictionary's keys.

Comment: I agree, it's a dictionary, but when I console log to chrome, that's what chrome says it is.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following fix time formats :

```
function put(key, value, obj) {
    obj[key] = value.replace(/(\b\d\b)/g,'0$1');
    return obj;
}
```

then use:

```
Object.keys(new_dict)
    .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))
    .forEach(p=>document.getElementById('next').innerHTML +="<br>" + p + " : " + 
new_dict[p] + "<br>");
```